# Can't Find NuGet with VS 2010 Shell Extension Manager

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nuget, visual-studio-shell

Following [these](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20Extension%20Manager%20to%20Install%20the%20Library%20Package%20Manager%20%28NuGet%29) instructions as best I can, the VS 2010 Shell Extension Manager turns up no results when searching for "nuget". The only deviation as far as I can tell is that the instructions show using VS 2010 Ultimate, and I am using the Shell. I had no problem with AnkhSvn and I can see all kinds of other extensions in the Online Gallery. One other thing, before attempting this I installed the NuGetPackageExplorer (not even really sure what it is, just trying to get off the ground with NuGet and I found it on their [CodePlex download site](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases) -- ultimately I'd like to publish my own NuGet package, since someone suggested it to me and I've heard about it a couple other times). Any Ideas?

**Update**

I recently got a new computer (Windows 7 64 bit) and freshly installed Visual Studio 2010 Shell and F# 2.0 and am having the same exact issue. Note: I just checked the About page and it says the only installed component is Visual Web Developer 2010 (seemed odd to me).

Comment: I just tried this, and it worked. Are you behind a firewall or going through a proxy?

Comment: No proxy, but I do have Windows Firewall active (Windows 7).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the Visual Studio 2010 "Shell" [1] is not one of the supported applications. Do you have a full version of Visual Studio 2010 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate?

From the NuGet FAQ page [2]:

> **What is required to run NuGet?**
>
> NuGet requires Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer Express 2010. The NuGet Package Manager Console requires that PowerShell 2.0 be installed. Powershell 2.0 is already installed if you have the following operating system:
>
> - Windows 7
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> If you have the following operating systems, you must manually install Powershell 2.0.
>
> - Windows XP SP3
> - Windows Server 2003 SP2
> - Windows Vista SP1
> - Windows Server 2008

[1] Is this the VS 2010 Shell you have? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=8e5aa7b6-8436-43f0-b778-00c3bca733d3

[2] http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq

Comment: At work I use VS 2010 Professional with NuGet happily, but at home I just have VS 2010 Shell (for F# hobby development) -- and yes, your link to the Shell is correct. Based on @Matthew M. Osborn authoritative comment, I think it is suppose to work but there must be some kind of bug (though the "Visual Studio 2010" requirement seems ambiguous in regard to commercial versions vs. Shell).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Check what's selected in the left pane of the Extensions Manager. It defaulted to "Installed Extensions" for me, that could be your problem. Select "Online Gallery -> All" then do the search again.

--

Not sure why it's not showing up, but you can install NuGet by going to [the website](http://nuget.org/) and clicking the blue "Install NuGet" button. This will take you through to a download page for the latest version (1.3).

Comment: Thanks @Danny, I thought for sure that your direct link to the download location would work, but when I executed the .vsix it said "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products."! (I quadruple checked that I selected "Online Gallery -> All" before doing the search).

Answer (score 1):

NuGet can be installed and updated using the Visual Studio Extension Manager. To check if your copy of Visual Studio already has the NuGet extension, look for Library Package Manager in the Tools menu of your copy of Visual Studio.

see documentation here :
http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started